# Can window snap be programmatically rotated when monitor is rotated to portrait?

Tags: windows-7, c#

My secondary monitor, which normally uses 1680x1050 resolution, is rotated (physically & through Windows) to be displayed vertically (1050x1680).

Is it possible, programmatically or via registry, to snap to the top and bottom of the screen rather than the left and right? The main display is not rotated, and would need to maintain the left/right snap.

Comment: What kind of "snap" are you talking about? Is this Aero snap, Windows Forms control positioning snap, the WPF equivalent, or something else?

Comment: Referring to Aero snap.

Comment: This sounds more of a question for superuser in my opinion.

Comment: I disagree, I'm not interested in an existing UI control or a built-in Windows functionality of the snap feature, rather a namespace or location to access it. But since it was edited and moved to another site I guess it doesn't really matter what I think.

Comment: return it to stackoverflow.com or close it...

Comment: @kokbira -- Can Justin do that with 16 respect points? I dunno, but probably not.

Comment: well, I'm "summoning" someone that have enough powers to do that :)

Comment: @The: RESPECT POINTS?

Comment: @Hello71 -- sorry, I messed it up, thought I am on a warez site :)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking.  Do you want to run a program which, while running, make Aero Snap use the top and bottom of the screen?  Run a program to toggle it?  Change it permanently?  Also, I doubt this is possible, because "drag to top of screen" is already defined as "maximize", which would conflict with what you want.

Comment: See the answer to:
http://superuser.com/questions/456031/can-i-aero-snap-to-the-top-bottom-instead-of-left-right-when-using-portrait-disp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy to do within the advanced graphics adapter settings.

> > rt click> Desktop> properties> advanced> { Intel/nVidia,ATI }
> >     or in Vista/win7> search >video settings> advanced

Tablets have hotkeys defined to rotate the display, you can program them with the driver package apps. but in your case a static setup of rotate display is all you want in the advanced settings. If not there go to the OEM for the drivers... eg. ATI/nVidia/Intel etc.

You can try using PROCMON to trace the EXE registry settings, but it may not be traceable if it is done by the DLL, so consider DEPENDS.exe to track the process namespace.