# Can I Aero-snap to the top/bottom instead of left/right when using Portrait display mode for a monitor?

Tags: windows-7, display, aero-snap, portrait

I want WINDOWS+LEFT and WINDOWS+RIGHT to snap to the top half and bottom half respectively.  Any solution works, be it a registry hack, driver setting, or program I can run.

This question is asking the same thing but the 'Answer' doesn't really answer anything:

[Can window snap be programmatically rotated when monitor is rotated to portrait?](https://superuser.com/questions/266171/can-window-snap-be-programmatically-rotated-when-monitor-is-rotated-to-portrait)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick Google search led me to an application called PowerResizer. It may be what you are looking for. I have never used it, so I cannot speak for its stability, it is simply what I came across.

- PowerResizer: http://sourceforge.net/projects/powerresizer/
- Some quick info: http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/powerresizer-extends-windows-7-aero-snap-windows-docking-features/

Comment: This works wonderfully (simply press W/Z while moving a window to snap to the top or bottom).  Thanks!